# how to skip the weekends while using the simple date format class in java

Tags: java, class, calendar

How to skip the weekends while using the simple date format class  in java. ie when i apply for  2 leaves on friday, it sholuld be applied for friday and monday not friday and saturday.

Comment: You can use Java 8's Time API, Joda-Time or if you're stuck, `Calendar`

Comment: Duplicate of many existing Questions. Thanks for participating, but please search StackOverflow before posting.

Comment: Then how to count friday and monday as holidays when we apply 2 days of leaves on friday.

Comment: public String CalculateToDate(String dateValue, Double days) {
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
  try {
   // Calculate ToDate
   double d = days;
   int daysnew = (int) d;
   Date fromDate = formatter.parse(dateValue);
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.setTime(fromDate);

   
   calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, daysnew);
   
   return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
  
  } catch (Exception e) {
   return null;
  }
 }